# Unloaded event not called in Secondary View in UWP app targeting 10240

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Following this example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views If I open any view in a secondary view, the Unloaded event of the Page opened in the Secondary Window never gets called. So there are many objects that are left without disposing properly, as I have some cleanup code in the Unloaded event.

I know that I can use the Consolidated event in the view to know when the secondary view is closed (Because the Closed event never gets called in the Window) But I cannot use this as I have some custom buttons that need to be unloaded before closing the secondary views. I can make some dirty patches but I want to avoid this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried it in latest version 17763?

Comment: I can't, have to target 10240

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot use this as I have some custom buttons that need to be unloaded before closing the secondary views.

The unloaded event will not be fired when you close the window. I did not understand why you could not use the Consolidated event. According to your description, you just want to do some clean operation before the window is closed. The [ApplicationView.Consolidated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.consolidated) occurs when the window is removed from the list of recently used apps, or if the user executes a close gesture on it. It exactly meets your requirement.

You could check the official [MultipleViews sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews). It implements a [ViewLifetimeControl.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/MultipleViews/cs/ViewLifetimeControl.cs) to control your secondary views and implements the release events and relevant functions to keep track of the secondary views and destroying the objects when closing.

Comment: Because I have a lot of custom UI elements where I need to run some logic and they relied on the Unloaded event that is not fired. What I don't understand is why the Unloaded event is not triggered when you close the window. I use the Consolidated event to cleanup the View and the ViewModel. The normal thing in clear would be to assume that when the Window is Closed, the UI elements get the Unloaded event called and then the  Closed event will be fired. But instead only the Consollidated event on the Window is called, it's quite missleading from my point of view.

Comment: I've checked that sample already, and I already have a class keeping track of the secondaryviews, but closing a Window SHOULD trigger the Unloaded events in all the UI elements, and then trigger the Closed event on the window....

Comment: @etragu It's a known issue. The relevant team is investigating it. Besides, could you please tell me why you have to stay on 10240?

Comment: Because we have clients that for business reasons they are confortable in the older version of 10240. It's basically the same reason why some people are still using Windows XP.